# Select specific record in CollectionVIewSource using code

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, entity-framework-6

Hie. I have what should be a simple question that's clearly above me. How to you get a collectionViewSource to select a specific record?

I've tried this:

```
private object Select_CommandExecute(object param)
{
    // Select * From Signups where Tag = '2';
    var select = context.signups.Where(s => s.tag == 2);
    return signupsViewSource.View.MoveCurrentTo(select);
}
```

But all it does is clear all fields. Any idea how I do this?
no matter what number I pass in, the result is always the same.

Comment: Not sure if we can pass a ***query*** into `MoveCurrentTo`? but as documentation says, the argument passed in should be an object representing the item. In this case you should use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Where`, then check if the `select` is not null before passing it into `MoveCurrentTo`.

Comment: @KingKing - Same result. How would you search for a row value if I may just ask? Is using a collection view even the right way to go about this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "clear[s] all fields"?  Do you mean it deselects the currently selected row(s)?

Comment: @MikeStrobel Yes. That's exactly what it does. If I'm using text boxes, they all go blank on button click

Answer (score 0):

I think Filter is what you are looking for. Here is a sample code using Filter.

```
IList<Employer> employers;
ICollectionView _employerView;
private string _filterString=string.Empty;
public Window1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   employers = GetCustomers();
   _employerView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(employers);
   _employerView.Filter = EmployerFilter;
}

public bool EmployerFilter(object item)
{
   Employer employer = item as Employer;
   return employer.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(_filterString.ToLower());
}

public string FilterString
{
   get { return _filterString; }
   set{
       _filterString = value; 
       OnPropertyChanged("FilterString");
       _employerView.Refresh();
 }   
}
```

Hope this help.